# What is the command to use the retire function in eosio.token

Tags: cleos, eosio.token

Can anyone give me the command line to retire (burn) tokens?

I couldn't find it in the developers portal but I see the function in the eosio.token abi

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access an action in a contract, you can simply push an action to that entry-point specifically. In your case:

```
$ cleos push action eosio.token retire '["20.000 SYS", "my memo"]' -p <issuer@permission>
```

assuming you want to retire 20.000 SYS tokens and the `eosio.token` contract is on the `eosio.token` account.